# How to remove the black bar appearing at the bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigationbar

I am new to Android Development. I want my app to support the screen size of my device i.e. `1080 x 2160 pixels`. Currently there is a black bottom bar that is displayed in place of where the navigation buttons would have been.

[image]

Please note that I do not want [Full Screen Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#java). **I have disabled the button navigation on my device. It is only for this app that that the bottom black rectangle is showing.** 
I just want my app to support the gesture navigation system of my device instead of buttons.How do I make the bottom bar go away using Java (`Android Studio`) so that my app utilizes that space?

Comment: Do you want to hide the navigation bar at the bottom?

Comment: Hiding the bottom navigation bar does not seem to work, even in the full screen I'm getting that bottom bar

Comment: Have you tried adding ```qemu.hw.mainkeys=1 (disable on screen buttons)``` to the bottom of your build.props?

Comment: I have already disabled on screen buttons on my device, It is only for this app that that the bottom black rectangle is showing. My problem is the similar to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33314057/8407719) question. But the answer does not solve it.

Answer (score 3):

question is old but I faced the same issue and didnot find the solution on SO.
this problem occurs for long screens

> We recommend that you design your app to support aspect ratios of 2.1 or higher. For this, you would add the following to the "application" element in your Manifest file:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
```

[from here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html)

Comment: Really appreciate. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, updated manifest file with this or remove if you have one.

**before**

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.max_aspect"
    android:value="2.1" />
```

**after**

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.max_aspect"
    android:value="2.4" />
```

working for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please Try below code

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    hideSystemUI(this, 1000);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        // Hide bar after 1 second
        hideSystemUI(this, 1000);
    }
}

public static void hideSystemUI(@NonNull final Activity activity, final int delayMs) {
    View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiState = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        hideSystemUI(activity, 1000);
                    }
                };
                handler.postDelayed(runnable, delayMs);
            }
        }
    });
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiState);
}
```

**WARNING**

If you have two activities, add this before changing

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(null);
```